# What is the format called when there is a bunch of numbers between backslashes?

Tags: decode

I'm currently reading through some code right now, and this stuff keeps appearing. How would I decode this, and what is it called?

```
\108\111\97\100\40\34\92\50\55\92\55\54\92\49\49\55\92\57\55\92\56\50\92\48\92\49\92\52\92\52\92\52\92\56\92\48\92\50\53\92\49\52\55\92\49\51\92\49\48\92\50\54
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the context in which you are seeing this?

Comment: 1. It's '\', not '/' as you say in the title. 2. Where do you see this?

Comment: It’s a sequence of bytes represented by decimal escape codes. The outer layer is ASCII text. If you’ve found this obfuscated in some other code, there’s a good chance it’s malware.

Answer (score 0):

It's (probably) unicode ASCII characters, represented as escape sequences.

`\108\111` is `lo`, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin

Answer (score 0):

It's byte data encoded as `\`-separated base-10 ints.  This is not a standard thing -- some kind of CTF exercise?  It looks like someone took a file, encoded it into a string inside some source code, and then encoded the source code itself the same way.

```
>>> code = r"108\111\97\100\40\34\92\50\55\92\55\54\92\49\49\55\92\57\55\92\56\50\92\48\92\49\92\52\92\52\92\52\92\56\92\48\92\50\53\92\49\52\55\92\49\51\92\49\48\92\50\54"
>>> print(''.join(chr(int(n)) for n in code.split("\\")))
load("\27\76\117\97\82\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\25\147\13\10\26
>>> code = r"27\76\117\97\82\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\25\147\13\10\26"
>>> print(''.join(chr(int(n)) for n in code.split("\\")))
←LuaR ☺♦ ↓“
```

The `LuaR` in the original encoded file is apparently the file header for compiled Lua.